# The term 'OMP_NUM_THREADS=1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, multithreading, powershell

When I am retying to set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 in windows. It gives me the following error:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 : The term 'OMP_NUM_THREADS=1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 python tools/train_net.py --config-file configs/FCO ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (OMP_NUM_THREADS=1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, it looks like you're using PowerShell. To set an environment variable in PowerShell you use the following syntax:

```
 $env:OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) for more information/details.

If you have any other, more specific issue (because all this has nothing to do with Python), you need to refine your question.